# Why Spring Integration failover doesn't show exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, failover

I have some problem with Spring Integration dispatcher's failover that should show me Exception if my Message Handler fails.

I have simple Spring integration context:

```
<int:gateway default-request-channel="inboundChannel"
             service-interface="com.some.gateway.PrinterGateway"/>

    <int:channel id="inboundChannel">
        <int:dispatcher failover="false"/>
    </int:channel>

    <!--first Message Handler (broken)-->    
    <bean id="printService" class="com.some.service.PrinterService"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="inboundChannel"
                           method="print"
                           ref="printService"/>

    <!--second Message Handler-->
    <bean id="uppercasePrintService"
          class="com.some.service.UppercasePrinterService"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="inboundChannel"
                           method="printUppercase"
                           ref="uppercasePrintService"/>
```

And my broken Message Handler class:

```
public class PrinterService {

    public void print(Message<String> message) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This is error");
    }
}
```

1. Can you explain me why my failover don't work?
2. Why RuntimeException is skipped and message was delivered to the next handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me.

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve; perhaps you misunderstand the load balancing?

By default, the load balancing strategy is round-robin, which means the first message will go to the failing endpoint; the second will go to the good endpoint.
Messages will alternate.

```
19:23:16.867 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel@1794d431', message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=9c3b1493-0a9a-e324-6da3-262079677ed0, timestamp=1494199396867}]
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'null'; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: foo, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=9c3b1493-0a9a-e324-6da3-262079677ed0, timestamp=1494199396867}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:449)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at com.example.So43836561Application.main(So43836561Application.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: foo
    at com.example.So43836561Application.lambda$0(So43836561Application.java:13)
    at com.example.So43836561Application$$Lambda$1/1121454968.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    ... 2 more
19:23:18.875 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel@1794d431', message: GenericMessage [payload=bar, headers={id=90aaa16c-a8c1-9162-ba8f-532fa3201c7f, timestamp=1494199398875}]
Second Service: GenericMessage [payload=bar, headers={id=90aaa16c-a8c1-9162-ba8f-532fa3201c7f, timestamp=1494199398875}]
19:23:18.876 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel@1794d431', message: GenericMessage [payload=bar, headers={id=90aaa16c-a8c1-9162-ba8f-532fa3201c7f, timestamp=1494199398875}]
```

If you use a NONE load balancing strategy, all messages will go to the failing one.

```
19:26:38.005 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel@7d9d1a19', message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=6a69efe9-dbbd-c79b-41a9-6964fd4c8ccc, timestamp=1494199598004}]
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'null'; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: foo, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=6a69efe9-dbbd-c79b-41a9-6964fd4c8ccc, timestamp=1494199598004}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:449)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at com.example.So43836561Application.main(So43836561Application.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: foo
    at com.example.So43836561Application.lambda$0(So43836561Application.java:13)
    at com.example.So43836561Application$$Lambda$1/2009787198.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    ... 2 more
19:26:40.009 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel@7d9d1a19', message: GenericMessage [payload=bar, headers={id=9428a10e-3a17-79d5-e4bd-731fc88ef0fe, timestamp=1494199600008}]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'null'; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: foo, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=bar, headers={id=9428a10e-3a17-79d5-e4bd-731fc88ef0fe, timestamp=1494199600008}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:449)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at com.example.So43836561Application.main(So43836561Application.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: foo
    at com.example.So43836561Application.lambda$0(So43836561Application.java:13)
    at com.example.So43836561Application$$Lambda$1/2009787198.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    ... 2 more
```

If that's not the problem, perhaps you have a second channel bean, with the same id that's configured differently?

Regardless, turning on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` will show you what's going on.

**EDIT**

Since you are using an async gateway (returns `Future<?>`) you need to examine the result to get the exception...

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
    List<Future<Message<String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Some payload that created for message id: " + i)
                .build();
        log.info("Sending message " + i);
        futures.add(gateway.print(message));
    }
    futures.forEach(f -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(f.get());
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause().getMessage());
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
public String printUppercase(Message<String> message) {
    log.info(message.getPayload().toUpperCase());
    return message.getPayload().toUpperCase();
}
```

result:

```
This is error
GenericMessage [payload=SOME PAYLOAD THAT CREATED FOR MESSAGE ID: 1, headers={id=229ad2ee-f424-61da-a9bc-a631de9bd5d0, timestamp=1494360966556}]
GenericMessage [payload=SOME PAYLOAD THAT CREATED FOR MESSAGE ID: 2, headers={id=7e2c45c4-2c7b-f3f3-243d-56d9de33375f, timestamp=1494360966556}]
This is error
This is error
This is error
GenericMessage [payload=SOME PAYLOAD THAT CREATED FOR MESSAGE ID: 6, headers={id=79f4ef60-9dea-60f3-3972-a9eefde67ebf, timestamp=1494360966556}]
GenericMessage [payload=SOME PAYLOAD THAT CREATED FOR MESSAGE ID: 7, headers={id=626d1347-e5bd-ec4c-b153-71174cc7f18d, timestamp=1494360966556}]
This is error
```

Comment: I haven't this stack trace after disabled my `failover`. And I want to show this trace that you attached, but load balancing behavior looks like enabled `failover`.

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying. As I said, what you are describing is impossible with the information you provided; something else must be in the picture. If you can post somewhere (github or similar) a complete example that exhibits the behavior you are seeing, someone will be able to figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You won't get the exception on the calling thread when you use an async gateway - you need to examine the Future<?>. BTW, you should set the reply timeout to 0 on the gateway if some flows might not return a result - otherwise you'll tie up a thread waiting for a result that will never come.

Comment: Yes, that's why I already used `Future<Message<String>>` as return type of my gateway method.

Comment: So now I am confused as to what your question is - the exception from the failing service is sitting in the `Future`. You said the failover didn't work when it clearly did.

Comment: Using a `Future` won't help with the hung thread - we still need a thread to populate the future when the result (or exception arrives) - the downstream flow might be async. It's better to use a `void` gateway if you don't expect a result, or set the reply timeout to 0.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my gateway to return type `void` and it fixed my problem.